# Allow MediaProjection Automatically without having the user interventions

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, screen-capture, android-mediaprojection

I want to add a screen capture activity in my app but I don't want to show the below dialog for the permissions. Is there any way that I can set permissions automatically for screen capture/screen share and by-pass this dialog? How to get the intent without this dialog and proceed with permissions granted?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to bypass any permission dialog. Without it your app wouldn't even have to permission to record the screen.

Comment: Can't we set any default permission in the manifest file to just allow it every time user accesses the app?